# Modal Popup causes access to crash

Tags: ms-access, crash, popup, modal-dialog

I am working on a modal popup form in access and I have the following problem:

When I incidentally open my form in "form view" instead of "design view" It causes a VB script error (which is normal, because it tries to get information from another form which is not open).

So VB tells me there's an error, I tell the VB debugger to stop the execution of the code, and thus the form does not open, but then access is not re-enabled.

I can't regain any form of control, and it's not an endless loop or something like that, because Access is still running correctly according to my task manager.

So far the only solution I found was to close access through the task manager, but it doesn't seem normal to me.

Comment: Do you have error checking going on?  Also if the code turns echo = false and then never turns it back on that can be an issue.

Comment: Ok I just figured this out...

I'm working on a dual screen, and for some reason I still don't understand, the popup was opening off-screen.

thank god this is an issue other people were facing so I found out what the origin of the problem was.

The solution was then to press Alt+Spacebar (brings up the contextual menu for the popup), choose the "move" option, then use keyboard arrows to move the popup to the right and finally click with my mouse to make the popup appear.

What a waste of 1 hour of my time

Comment: Ok the problem now is that whatever I do, the form keeps opening off-screen.

I even set the auto-centre option to "yes" to no avail.

I tried to restart access, restart my computer, nothing works. The forms (all my popup forms, even newly created ones) open off-screen.

WTF is this, what can I do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/control-location-screen-form-opens-t4041436.html

You can also try to modify a bit of your form, move it to a new/good position, and saving it. I have had this happen to me in the past.